# Sending input as json and receiving the ouput as json using java HttpURLConnection and Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I want to send the input as `json` using the `HttpURLConnection` in java client and the request will be handled by the Spring MVC library `jacksonhaus` to response the output as `json`

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.test.com/SpringMVC/rest/service/getEmpDetails");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String input = "{\"name\":\"emp1\",\"add\":\"emp2\"}";

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes());
os.flush();

if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
        + conn.getResponseCode());
}
```

When i use this code i am getting

> HTTP error code : 500

In Spring MVC am using the model Attribute for the input Request. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your controller code are you sending `http_created` from controller? should you be looking for `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK`.

Below code may help you

**Controller code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jsonconsumer", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String consumer(@RequestBody JavaBean javaBean) {
    return "created";
}
```

**JavaBean code:**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class JavaBean {

    private String name = "";
    private String add = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAdd() {
        return add;
    }

    public void setAdd(String add) {
        this.add = add;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JavaBean {name=[" + name + "], add=[" + add + "]}";
    }
}
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/getEmpDetails")
 public @ResponseBody String  validateRequest(@ModelAttribute("resource") EmpBean empBean){
  
  return "true";
 }` this is my controller code

Comment: I copied your controller and it returns fine i get following in logs. <<<<<<<<<<<<GOT OBJECT>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>EmpBean  {name=[emp], add=[emp1]}
RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [true] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@11c21b]. Is there something to do with Webserver you are running , I use tomcat 7, also you should expect HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK not HTTP_CREATED.